# Setting content of iframe using javascript fails in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, iframe

I'm trying to set the content of a iframe using javascript.

I've the html string. And I'm writing:-

```
 var iframe = $('iframe')[0],
 content = '<div>test</div>';        
 $(iframe).contents().find('html').html(content);
```

It works fine in google chrome, but in firefox is shows the content for a moment and the disappears. 
Please help me to fix it.

Comment: That was my typing mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same problem. I saw the load function of iframe fires in firefox but not in chrome. So firefox reload the iframe again on load event.

So with your existing code try this:-

```
   $(iframe).load(function(e){
      $(iframe).contents().find('html').html(content);

    })
```

Comment: It worked, but is it good practise to write the same code twice?

Comment: @DeadlyDemon then you should refactor it and move it to a separate function. Write `function foo() {$(iframe).contents().find('html').html(content);}` `:)` and then call `foo()` from both places. +1 to the post.