# How to make ifram work in firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox

[Setting content of iframe using javascript fails in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686443/setting-content-of-iframe-using-javascript-fails-in-firefox)

I looked at this thread and it doesn't work for me or I don't understand it.
I would comment there but I am limited due to my reputation level.

I am using this line of code and on chrome it works

```
$("#wOutput").contents().find("html").html("Hi");
```

Any idea?